# Apache POI hsmf - MAPIMessage not findable

Tags: java, apache-poi

I will use Apache POI in order to read Outlook msg messages but I can not find the class MAPIMessages (**import org.apache.poi.hsmf.MAPIMessage**). I use the version 3.16.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**poi-3.16-beta1.jar** dont contain *org.apache.poi.hsmf.MAPIMessage*, if you want to use it you should use [poi-scratchpad-3.16-beta1.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad/3.16-beta1)